# Why does IDEA report errors for build.sbt in a new sbt project?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm running IntelliJ 13.1.5 community edition. I've got JDK, Scala, SBT installed. The JAVA_HOME, JDK_HOME, SCALA_HOME and SBT_HOME variables are set. If I create a new SBT project, after initial sbt refresh, I get this:

[image: intellij error]

The thing compiles and runs fine, even if I add dependencies, but the file itself shows tonnes of errors. F4 settings show empty SBT module stuff:

[image: empty module]

I then installed https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea and ran sbt gen-idea in the project folder. This created a bunch of files, and reloading the project, the reds in the sbt file went away.

This is on my laptop. However, on my work machine, simply creating a new project works fine, and the sbt file isn't filled with red. Can't seem to figure out how that machine's different. Any pointers on how to resolve this annoying issue?

Comment: I encountered the same problem by miss-checking import xx-build project. Import all, and not problem again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, check if you added the  “scala-library*.jar” to Scala compiler library

This link might be helpful:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2010/09/02/project-configuration-explained/

If you are using windows or linux, please also see:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Setting+up+Scala+plugin+project+in+IntelliJ+IDEA

Comment: It does seem related. I completely removed Java, JDK, Scala, SBT and IntelliJ, deleted all .sbt folders in home folder, etc. I reinstalled IntelliJ, installed the scala plugin, and created a new project. Same error. However.... I can see that IntelliJ is looking for the scala-library.jar file in E:\.sbt\...\scala-library.jar. After the project is made and run, I notice there's no .sbt folder in E:\, but there is one in C:\Users\Ashic\.sbt, with the expected contents. Is there a way to ensuring either a) E:\.sbt is used or b) telling intelliJ to use C:\Users\Ashic\.sbt?

Comment: I copied the relevant jars of C:\Users\Ashic\.sbt to E:\.sbt and everything seems to be working. Would be good if I could have sbt always use E:\.sbt though.

Comment: Managed to solve it. On my laptop, I've changed the location of my docs, music, home folders, etc (to the E: drive). There's apparently some issue with some jvm programs where some point to the mapped, but others point to the folder in C:\Users\Foo. I could have junctioned C:\Users\Ashic to E:\ but since there's a lot of stuff in there, I junctioned a new sbt folder to E:\.sbt (same for ivy2 & m2). This solves all issues. 

For reference, the command is:
mklink /j C:\Users\Foo\.sbt E:\.sbt

where the .sbt in C: doesn't exist.

Thanks for ur help. Pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9):

In case IntelliJ IDEA struggles a bit with caching, try the first and if still not working the second should definitely do the trick:

- File -> Invalidate cache and restart
- Close IDEA, delete .idea, re-import your project

Answer (score 7):

I was also getting highlighted errors in all of the build.sbt file. 
What fixed it was to select to Download "Sources for SBT and plugins" in the Import Project from SBT window.

Comment: didn't help here unfortunately.

Comment: Unbelievable - the only change I made and it worked.  What's going on with IntelliJ Scala support? (It compiles fine in SBT, but IDEA throws all kinds of nonsensical errors without having Sources checked as you mentioned.

Comment: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/IntellijSbtJava.html

Answer (score 1):

> Update on 2020, Apr

This works for scala 2.13 and Intellij 2020.1 when:

- sbt files has error
- project structure is wrong

Reason is 'External libraries' from sbt is not loading for IDE.

To do so, similar to old version: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/IntellijSbtJava.html

[image]

```
1. rm -rf .ida
2. Click Menu item: Open... to pick the project directory
```

---

If not working, I assume you need to setup Global SDK for intellij by
`cmd+;` and pick the path of scala.

In case of mac,
`brew install scala` normally echo out the path `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea`

Let ide browse to this path by holding `cmd+shift+G` to open path.

IDE should find the path like `/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.13.1/idea/lib/scala-library.jar` and `scala-compiler.jar` and `scala-reflect.jar`

There might be better way to do the global scala setting though.